# Runtime error when pressing like button

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I just want to save the number of likes and the people who liked in the posts table under the key of the post

Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). [Here is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6ttB.png)

```
 @IBAction func didtaplike(_ sender: Any) {

    print("like tappppppppped")
    self.loggedinuser = Auth.auth().currentUser
    let key =  ref.child("posts").childByAutoId().key

    ref.child("posts").child(self.loggedinuser!.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let post = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
            print(post)
          let updatelikes :[String:Any] = ["userswholiked/\(key)" : Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid]
             self.ref.child("posts").child(self.loggedinuser!.uid).updateChildValues(updatelikes)


        }


    })


  }
```

This is in the home view controller and the like button is in the tableview cell

```
       override func viewDidLoad() {

          super.viewDidLoad()

    self.ac.startAnimating()

    self.loggedinuser = Auth.auth().currentUser

    self.databaseref.child("users").child(self.loggedinuser!.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) {
        (snapshot:DataSnapshot) in

        let  snao = snapshot.value as! [String:AnyObject]
        if (snao["pc"] != nil) {
        self.x = snao["pc"] as! String
        }

        if let t    = snao as AnyObject?
        {
            self.loggedinuserdata = t
        }

        //  print(self.loggedinuserdata)

        self.databaseref.child("posts").child(self.loggedinuser!.uid).observe(.childAdded, with: {( snap: DataSnapshot) in

            let snapp = snap.value as! [String:AnyObject]
            if let x = snapp["text "] as! String? {
                self.posts.insert(x, at: 0)

            }

            self.feeds.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row : 0 ,section : 0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
            self.feeds.reloadData()

            self.ac.stopAnimating()
        }

        )}


}
```

Comment: Where are you updating your table view? Because this code doesn t show me where is that

Comment: check the update

Comment: And where are your table view data from? numberOfRowsInSection , cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Why do you call `insertRows` and `reloadData`? That's pointless. Only call one of the two.

Comment: from firebase database table posts it receives the text and displays it @incmiko

Comment: i know but this is not the problem . help me solve the problem @rmaddy

Comment: It is a problem. Pick one first so we know what you are actually dealing with. If you remove `insertRows` and leave `reloadData`, your issue will be fixed. If you want to fix `insertRows` after removing `reloadData`, then we can focus on that issue.

Comment: i removed insert rows and it worked . but in the firebase database when i make a new post the " userswholiked  " doesn't stay under the key of the post it is just a different key i want every post to have its " users who liked"